# Text and Select not aliigned to same line

Tags: css

I have a site(www.excoflare.com/dev2011/socialnetwork) . As you can see in search field my text and select is not alligned to the same line . How can I alligned them to the same line ?

Comment: you mean make align for the value of the text and search box rite?

Comment: Ya.U see the fields are not equal . The select box is lower than the text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add `float:left` to input

Answer (score 1):

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/8hzW7/

I have place li for text and selecbox and give style `float:left` for li. then it will works.